# how can I export my mysql database in webmatrix3

Tags: mysql, webmatrix-3

I created database in webmatrix3 using mysql now i would like to generate .sql dump file to create same database in another machine but i could not found any option to do that can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL you can generate the sql file using [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) from the command line:

`mysqldump -u username -p database > out.sql`

(fill in your username, and database)

You also might want to add the parameter `--routines` to also export functions and procedures of the database.  And to import the data in the database into the same or another machine:

`mysql -u username -p -D database < out.sql`

Also be sure that the new database has the correct user access. More detailed information can be found in the [MySQL reference manual of mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html).